# Compute the line integral of $x^2 + y^2$ on curve $|x|+|y|=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, line-integrals

> Compute the integral
> $$\int_{\gamma} f(x,y)ds$$
> where $\gamma=\{|x|+|y|=1\}$ and $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$

Note, we have not covered any major theorems on evaluating line integrals, which has been presented is to parametrize the curve then integrate with respect to the parameter(roughly speaking). However, I have no idea how to paramatrize the curve. My intuition tells me we should probably split the curve into four cases, but then the derivative of the parametrizations will be zero? So how would I proceed? Input would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3+\gamma_4$

Comment: "but then the derivative of the parametrizations will be zero?" - This should not happen. Can you provide your parametrizations?

Comment: @Klaus I was thinking $x=-1,x=1,y=-1,y=1$, but I'm not quite sure about this.

Comment: @BobDobbs yes I get that, but what should the $\gamma$'s be?

Comment: @William These are not parametrizations. A parametrization is a (differentiable) map $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3+\gamma_4$ is the obvious sum of line segments: 1) $\gamma_{1}$ joins $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. 2) $\gamma_{2}$ joins $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$. 3) $\gamma_{3}$ joins $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$. 4) 2) $\gamma_{4}$ joins $(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Then, $I=\int_{\gamma}(x^2+y^2)ds=\sum_{i=1}^4I_{i}$ where $I_i=\int_{\gamma_{i}}(x^2+y^2)ds$.

(1) Parametrization of $\gamma_1$: $x=t$, $y=1-t$, $0\leq t\leq 1$. Then $dx=dt$, $dy=-dt$, $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{2}dt$. Hence, $I_1=\int_0^1(t^2+(1-t)^2)\sqrt{2}dt=\sqrt{2}\int_0^1(2t^2-2t+1)dt=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.$

(2) Parametrization of $\gamma_2$: $x=t$, $y=t+1$, $-1\leq t\leq 0$. Then $dx=dt$, $dy=dt$, $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{2}dt$. Hence, $I_1=\int_{-1}^0(t^2+(1+t)^2)\sqrt{2}dt=\sqrt{2}\int_{-1}^0(2t^2+2t+1)dt=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.$
Here, we noticed that the orientation is not important.(Why?) Let's dicuss this. It is confusing. We could choose a counter-clockwise orientation of $\gamma_2$: $x=-t$, $y=1-t$, $0\leq t\leq 1$. Then $dx=-dt$, $dy=-dt$, $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{2}dt$. Hence, $I_1=\int_{0}^1((-t)^2+(1-t)^2)\sqrt{2}dt=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^1(2t^2-2t+1)dt=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.$ Same result.

It seems that (3) and (4) computations will give the same result: $\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$. Therefore, $I=4(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3})=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}$.

Comment: I hope they give the same number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive answer!

Answer (score 3):

The curve is made of 4 lines in the 4 Quadrants.
Each line has the same value of the required Integral , because of the Squaring & the Modulus , which will convert all Negatives to Positives.

Explaining that Observation : With $(+a,+b)$ on the curve , we will get $(-a,+b) , (+a,-b) , (-a,-b)$ on the curve.  Squaring , we always get $+a^2+b^2$ in all the 4 Quadrants.

Taking first Quadrant , we can use the line $U=1-V$ matching the 2 Corners & the mid-Point.
Now we can Integrate over this line & take 4 times.

[image: INTEGRATE]

Comment: Thank you! Made it much clearer, (I drew a regular square which was my point of confusion) :)

Comment: Nice to know that it was useful !